# Javascript 'number' and postgres types

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I'm using postgres with node.js via the `pg` package, I'm only starting off so I'm aiming for a very simple table of the form shown below, created in the `psql` shell by the command

```
CREATE TABLE people(id int, name text);

Column   |  Type   | Modifiers
------------+---------+-----------
    id   | int     |
    name | text    |
```

The relevant parts of the node file are shown below. All I'm trying to do is get a count of the current number of people (which is fine), increment it by `1` and use this new value as the `id` of the next person I add to the table

```
pg.connect(conString, function(err, client) {
  var count;
  var next;

  client.query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM people', function(err, result) {
    count = result.rows[0].count;
    next = Number(count)+1;
  });

  client.query('INSERT INTO people (id, name) VALUES ($1, $2)', [next, req.body.personName],function(err, result) {
  });
});
```

The `req.body.personName` is being set elsewhere in the `express` app, there is no problem with that part of it, the name gets stored fine in postgres but the `id` column remains blank.

I have

- tried both `numeric` and `int` types when creating the field in postgres but it made no difference
- Assuming the problem to be an incompatibility between types as they are defined in postgres, and the looser definition in javascript I have tried to cast the type `VALUES ($1::int, $2)` , again to no avail
- I thought the `[node-pg-types][1]` project might be a solution, but from what I understand of it, it isn't (I could well be wrong)
- If I replace the `next` variable in the `client.query` call with either a `1` or `'1'` (or any other number/string) then `1` will appear as the id in postgres

Comment: ok, `console.log(result.rows[0].count)` gives `0` (table is empty, so correct), but it is of type `string`. Not sure what you mean with the `alias` suggestion? Could you please expand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're doing two things at once (asynchronously).  Try the INSERT after the query finishes (in the callback):

```
pg.connect(conString, function(err, client) {
  var count;
  var next;

  client.query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM people', function(err, result) {
    count = result.rows[0].count;
    next = Number(count)+1;
    client.query('INSERT INTO people (id, name) VALUES ($1, $2)', [next,              
       req.body.personName],function(err, result) {
    });
  });


});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! I feel like a right idiot that I missed that!